# Format a variable after a character in a string

Tags: php

I'm using a variable called $contact_location a few times.

It works fine up until I need to use it for a URL.

Example string:

```
"Hello, from $contact_location, please visit www.ourwebsite.com/$contact_location"

output: Hello, from New Mexico, please visit www.ourwebsite.com/New Mexico.

Needed Output: Hello, from New Mexico, please visit www.ourwebsite.com/new-mexico
```

Is there a way to format a variable only if it comes after something like ".com/"

The url should read www.ourwebsite.com/new-mexico

I know how to str_replace

```
str_replace(" ","-",$contact_location);
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want the variable after *.com* or should it replace *.com*?

Comment: the variable after .com so the URL is correct. eg: ourwebsite.com/new-mexico

Comment: Make use of regex to do this.

Comment: thanks, i'll have to learn how to do that.

Comment: You don't want to format into a variable before ? Like using `$contactFormated` which will contain `new-mexico` ?

Comment: They're already using $contact_location, so I need that to work in other parts of the string like it does. I just need to format it when it's being used in their URL and there's two words.

Comment: just realized I didn't have ".com/" in the url. added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
function formatUrl($msg)
{    
    $pattern = '/www\..*/';
    preg_match($pattern, $msg, $matches);
    return preg_replace($pattern, strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$matches[0])),$msg);
}

$contact_location = 'New Mexico';
$msg = formatUrl("Hello, from $contact_location, please visit www.ourwebsite/$contact_location");
var_dump($msg);
```

By using `preg_match` and `preg_replace`, you can easilly perform a replacement in string based on a pattern.

I was assuming then you're looking for a web site content to change, so, my pattern is `'/www\..*/'`. But, if you want to change it, to `.com` as mentioned on your question, just replace `$pattern` value to your desired match.

[Here, a simple regex trainning](https://regexone.com).

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "Your text will be here www.yourdomain.com";
$contact_location = "new-maxico";
if (stripos($text, ".com") !== false) {
   $text = $text . "/" . $contact_location;
}
```

This will help you for sure

Comment: thanks, but I need to use $contact_location before the url and have it unchanged.

Comment: I  think you have mentioned that you need it after the URL in above comment mate.

So, Can you share me how you want to may be I can help you?

Comment: See above. I said I need the $contact_location to be unchanged if it's not in the URL. yours changes it everywhere